# Merge vectors based on values in both (in R)

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 vectors "x" and "y". I would like to add the letters that are in "x" only if they are not yet in y.

```
x <- c(a, b, c, d, e)
y <- c(a, z, m, d, e, g)

result
r <- c(b, c, a, z, m, d, e, g)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we need `union`

```
union(x, y)
```

or if we need the same order

```
c(setdiff(x, y), y)
```

`setdiff` or `union` returns the unique elements.  If there are duplicates and want them all

```
library(vecsets)
c(vsetdiff(x, y), y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other base R options:

- If you should keep duplicates, you can try this way

```
c(x[is.na(match(x,y))],y)
```

- If you try to keep unique values

```
unique(c(x,y))
```